# Query filter different criteria

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Is it possible for me to query filter data by month? I want the YEAR, ID, NAME and CLASS columns to remain the same but the PAGE and CHAPTER data change according to the set month.

The query filter in sheet name 'Query'

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hCe1YdTPUq3AkxGAmVe2CMhnuAch5p5UD7YT1HFTj5M/edit?usp=sharing
Details

Tried to change formula but is not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `FILTER` based solution to your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hCe1YdTPUq3AkxGAmVe2CMhnuAch5p5UD7YT1HFTj5M/edit#gid=524467545). Please do test it out.

```
=LAMBDA(z,FILTER(FILTER(DATA!$A3:$Z,REGEXMATCH(COLUMN(DATA!1:1)&"","\b1\b|\b2\b|\b3\b|\b4\b|\b"&z&"\b|\b"&z+1&"\b")),REGEXMATCH(DATA!$A3:$A,IF($B3="ALL",TEXTJOIN("|",1,UNIQUE(DATA!$A3:$A)),$B3)),REGEXMATCH(INDEX(DATA!$A3:$Z,,z+1),IF($B4="ALL",TEXTJOIN("|",1,UNIQUE(INDEX(DATA!$A3:$Z,,z+1))),TEXTJOIN("|",1,UNIQUE({$B4,$C4,$D4},1))))))(XMATCH(A6,DATA!1:1))
```

- 

[image]